# woocommerce how to get current category

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, woocommerce

I am accessing `archive-products.php` on woocommerce to display my products (like the normal process in woocommerce).

On the page of archive-products.php I have added the sidebar with all the product categories that my shop has (with or without products). I have used the following code to do so:

```
$taxonomy = 'product_cat';
$orderby = 'ID';
$show_count = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$pad_counts = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$hierarchical = 1;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$title = '<h2>' . _x('Our Products', 'mfarma') . '</h2>';
$hide_empty = 0;

$args = array(
    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
    'orderby' => $orderby,
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'show_count' => $show_count,
    'pad_counts' => $pad_counts,
    'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
    'title_li' => $title,
    'hide_empty' => $hide_empty
);
?>

<ul>
    <?php wp_list_categories($args); ?>
</ul>
```

Now the left side of the page has the above sidebar and the right one has the products. In each product category I have added a small description with an html format that I want to show when the user has clicked the category. According to woocommerce when you go to a specific category (in my case, `http://localhost/product-category/mycategory`) it is still the archive-products.php.

I am trying to get the term_id from the link clicked, but the loop (and the global $post) points me to the first product of the list instead of the category that I need. So if a category has zero products, I can't get the `term ID`. How do I get that term ID from archive-products.php?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Found the answer for something else but it also applies to my question.

```
add_action('woocommerce_archive_description', 'woocommerce_category_description', 2);

function woocommerce_category_description() {
    if (is_product_category()) {
        global $wp_query;
        $cat = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
        echo "CAT IS:".print_r($cat,true); // the category needed.
    }
}
```

Comment: And you put this where?

Comment: In functions.php for the theme, or in a plugin.php if you are doing something more generic and you need it.

Comment: I want to show image also with in my specific HTML, Will you please explain is this possible via action or either i have to use some query in archive-products.php

Answer (score 11):

You can do it simplier:
**Print current category:**

```
single_cat_title(); // this prints your current category
```

**Get current category string:**

```
single_cat_title('', false); // this returns your current category
echo single_cat_title('', false); // for print current category
```