# How to get all products from current WooCommerce product category?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, woocommerce, taxonomy-terms

Customizing my `archive-product.php`. How can I show only products within a certain category in a custom loop? [This similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15330666/woocommerce-custom-loop-to-get-all-product-from-one-specific-category), didn't solve my problem. I tried `single_cat_title()` to get the current category based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24138701/woocommerce-how-to-get-current-category) question but got an error. I think I need to use `get_queried_object()` based on this [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object/) but I keep getting errors.

I tried this:

```
<?php 
$category = single_cat_title('', false); // this returns your current category ?>

<?php
// Setup your custom query
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'product', 
    'product_cat' => $category,
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        <br>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); // Remember to reset ?>
```

I also tried:

```
`$term_name = get_queried_object()->name;`
    // Setup your custom query
    $args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'product', 
        'product_cat' => $term_name, );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated**

On product category archive pages, to get the current product category term you will use:

- [Wordpress function `get_queried_object()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object/) *(to get the WP_Term Oject)*.
- or [Wordpress function `get_queried_object_id()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object_id/) *(to get the term Id)*.

Using directly the taxonomy parameter in a WP_Query is deprecated since WordPress 3.1. Instead you will use a **tax query** as follow:

```
<?php
// Get The queried object ( a WP_Term or a WP_Post Object)
$term = get_queried_object();

// To be sure that is a WP_Term Object to avoid errors
if( is_a($term, 'WP_Term') ) :

// Setup your custom query
$loop = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'tax_query'      => array( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat', // The taxonomy name
        'field'    => 'term_id', // Type of field ('term_id', 'slug', 'name' or 'term_taxonomy_id')
        'terms'    => $term->term_id, // can be an integer, a string or an array
    ) ),
) );

if ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
echo '<div style="margin:8px; text-align:center;">
    <a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">';
the_post_thumbnail();
the_title();
echo '</a></div>';
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata(); // Remember to reset
endif; endif;
?>
```

Tested and works.

Documentation:  [`WP_Query` and Taxonomy Parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters)

Comment: Thank you. I added your code but I'm now getting "There has been a critical error on your website"?

Comment: is it possible to get `the_post_thumbnail ( 'thumbnail' );` wrapped in the_permalink only? I can't get the thumbnail to reduce in size to 'thumbnail' with echo `'<a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">';
the_post_thumbnail();
echo '</a>';

Comment: @newbieneedshelp Just move  `echo '</a></div>';` before `the_title();`

Comment: I had tried this but it won't display the image as 'thumbnail' rather image becomes extra large in size. This only happens when wrapped in permalink. This is what I tried: echo `'<div style="margin:8px; text-align:center;">
    <a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">';
the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail');
echo '</a></div>';`

Comment: Did you tried: `<a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">';
the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');
echo '</a>';
the_title();
echo '</div>';`

Comment: Thanks, tried this but same problem - image is blown up. Only way I can get 'thumbnail' size image is to not to wrap it in a href...?