# How to get products in a specific category & current category in an archive?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, taxonomy

I'm making a custom archive template in WooCommerce and I'm wanting to show products in a specific category + in the current category.

Below code works to output the specific category but how do I find the current category the page is in?

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'product_cat'    => 'categoryx'
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        global $product;
                echo 'Add Some Stuff Here to Do Something';
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: if you are trying to get the current category in Woocommerce read the [Woocommerce Theme Developer Handbook](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-theme-developer-handbook/) documentation or you can take a look at open source themes how they handle it.  Maybe this is your answer [woocommerce how to get current category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24138701/woocommerce-how-to-get-current-category)

Comment: OK that works. I can use the title rather than ID, so using `single_cat_title('', false);`  does the job. Thank you!